# How do I use toastr?

Tags: javascript, html, toastr

I like the idea of what I can do with toastr, but I can't seem to get it to work.

From the official page...

```
(1) Link to toastr.css
(2) Link to toastr.js
(3) Use toastr to display a toast for info, success, warning or error
To install toastr, run the following command in the Package Manager Console
Install-Package toastr
```

I downloaded the command-line version of NuGet and typed in `install toastr` and it successfully installed, (although I have no idea what it actually did.......) then, in my page, `test.php`, I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/toastr.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/toastr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
toastr.info('Hey - it works!');
</body>
```

The website itself says this is incredibly simple....

```
// Display an info toast with no title

toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')
```

but when I execute the page, all I see is literally:

**toastr.info('Hey - it works!');**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to review a rudimentary javascript tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You could just add your script tag before your close body tag, and also, use it in a valida javascript scope.

```
.. all html page

<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // show when page load
        toastr.info('Hey - it works!');

    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You also have other methods,

```
// for success - green box
toastr.success('Success messages');

// for errors - red box
toastr.error('errors messages');

// for warning - orange box
toastr.warning('warning messages');

// for info - blue box
toastr.info('info messages');
```

Comment: I guess I don't know how to use javascript, which I need to in order to use this.  I put the code `$(document).ready(function() {

    // show when page load
    toastr.info('Page Loaded!');

    $('#linkButton').click(function() {
       // show when the button is clicked
       toastr.success('Click Button');

    });

});` into my page, but it doesn't do anything, it just echoes the code.... do I need to wrap this in something?

Comment: All javascript code MUST be between <script> and </script> tags otherwise the browser won't recognise it as javascript.